# How to read current history of a still logged in user?

Tags: debian, history

I currently have a root SSH session on a Debian Wheezy server, and I see that another user is currently logged in (with an unprivileged account). As the user is still logged in, the command `history` is not showing the right thing because the history was not flushed and then the `~/.bash_history` file is not up to date (it's still in memory).

How can I dump memory to see what a user has done during his session when he's still logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a small script that should dump the history. Notice that you need to be root to sneak memory space of other processes.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "usage: $0 <bash_pid>"
        exit 1
fi
gdb -batch \
        --eval "set sysroot /" \
        --eval "attach $1" \
        --eval "call write_history(\"/tmp/bash_history-$1.txt\")" \
        --eval 'detach' \
        --eval 'q'
exit 0
```

p.s. Seeing error like 'warning: Could not load shared library symbols for...' can happen along with few other error looking lines. Try to find the history file from /tmp/ before begin too convinced the script did not work.

Comment: Excellent, very good job! Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really rely on bash_history because it is not always saved or can be over-written. Also not everything is usually saved during multi-session use (that depends on configuration of course).

If you really need such data tracked then I would go on setting up `acct` which has useful tools like:

- `ac` command prints the statistics of user logins/logouts (connect time) in hours.
- `lastcomm` command prints the information of previously executed commands of user.
- `accton` command is used to turn on/off process for accounting.
- `sa` command summarizes information of previously executed commands.
- `last` and `lastb`commands show listing of last logged in users.

To install:

```
apt-get install acct
```

Then you must enable the service

```
service pcacct start
```